# Symfony app getting 403 error?

Tags: php, api, symfony

I have a react frontend that is connecting to a Syfmony 3 backend.  However when I do a fetch request to my syfmony controller I get a 403 error.

The fetch request looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch('/lessons', {
method: 'get', headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
console.log("test" + response);

}).catch(function(err) {
});
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
class LessonsController extends FOSRestController {

/**
* @Rest\Get("/lessons")
*/
public function getAction()
{
$restresult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Lesson')->findAll();
if ($restresult === null) {
  return new View("there are no users exist", 
Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
}
  return $restresult;
}
}
```

I thought maybe it was a problem with my NelmioCORS bundle which is set up like this:

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    allow_credentials: false
    allow_origin: []
    allow_headers: []
    allow_methods: []
    expose_headers: []
    max_age: 0
    hosts: []
    origin_regex: false
    forced_allow_origin_value: ~
paths:
    '^/lessons/':
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: ['GET']
        max_age: 3600
```

My security.yml looks like this:

```
security:

access_control:
    - { path: ^/lessons , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY} 


firewalls:
  dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

  main:
    anonymous: ~
```

Thank you!

Comment: check your security.yml, seems like a permission problem with your requested URL

Comment: Hi there, I've added the security.yml but I'm really not sure how to configure it!

Comment: access_control:
    - { path: ^/lessons , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}

Comment: thanks but I'm getting the same error!

Comment: I think the problem with nelmio_cors configuraton.try to change your allow_methods or comment out configuration to be sure from where the error comes in.

Comment: I commented out the nelmio_cors config and I'm still getting the error so guess its not there!  hmm thanks!

Comment: is your another route working?

Comment: No none of the routes are working!

Comment: show me your security.yml file

Comment: Hi there, I've added the security.yml, thanks!

Comment: Here is a suggestion that you may not have thought of. Are the Symfony files owned by the user that your web server is running as? It could be the Apache or whatever web server you are using doesn't have permission to access the files.